# Creating .obj files in Java

Tags: java, jogl, wavefront, .obj

is there a Java library in existence for creating .obj files. There are many for loading .obj files for use with APIs like JOGL but I can't find anything to do with creating an .obj file.

Comment: What is an .obj file? Is it a file format for a special application? If so, please tag the question appropriately please.

Comment: obj files are generic 3D objects. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3a-Export-from-Java3D-to-.obj-p19550694.html) could help, it's referring to a [`ObjWriter`](http://sweethome3d.cvs.sourceforge.net/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D/src/com/eteks/sweethome3d/swing/OBJWriter.java?view=markup) class, with usage example:

```
// Open the OBJ file "MyObject.obj" 
OBJWriter writer = new OBJWriter("MyObject.obj"); 

// Write one node or more if you want 
writer.writeNode(java3DNode1); 
writer.writeNode(java3DNode2); 
// ... 

// Close file. This will create the MTL file and texture files in same directory 
writer.close();
```